# When pressing enter key, automatically skips a line in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Not sure why but when I press enter within the cell to type on the next line, it skips a line instead, i.e. there's now a blank line in between my 1st and 2nd line of code. Happens each time I press enter. Not sure if anyone encountered this before.

```
# this is my first line
(empty line)
# my cursor jumps to 3rd line by just pressing enter once
```

Comment: Does this happen in Markdown cell? . It it does try following <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906199/how-to-make-a-new-line-in-a-jupyter-markdown-cell>

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! Just managed to resolve the issue, it was due to some of my google chrome extensions...